# Setup mvn clean package -P profile_name in eclipse in eclipse run configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven

Consider a project which till now used to be built using:

```
mvn clean package -P pname
```

in terminal and deployed manually to tomcat's `webapps` folder.

How to setup the run configuration and deployment for this in eclipse?

Here's what I've tried in Eclipse Oxygen:

Created a new `Maven Build` Run Configuration like this - set the `Base directory` of the project, set the `Goals` to `clean package` and `Profiles` to `local`.
Once run, I tried deploying the project to the tomcat set up in eclipse.

The issue is that there is difference between the runs when I am building and deploying manually and when I am using the eclipse configuration that I have made. The `pname` part is not being picked properly.